# Rails 3 - Create record on tick of a checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3.2 , how do you create multiple records on tick of a check box ?

In my view I use as

```
= check_box_tag 'product[product_ids][]', product.id
```

I checked the development logs and the checkbox values are as

```
"product"=>{"product_ids"=>["193", "195"]}
```

And in the controller I do something as

```
@cpr = CouponProductRestriction.new(params[:product])
@cpr.save
```

But I get an error as

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: product_ids
```

Is there something I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates it is not the problem of the checkbox. You just need to add an `attr_accessible` declaration. In other words add the following line in the Product model:

```
attr_accessible :product_ids
```